# orientdb rename column with sql syntax

Tags: sql, orientdb

I am trying to rename column name in ORIENTDB VERSION 2.1.14 with SQL

having a "USER" vertex like

```
+------+------+-----+
|  cc  | name | cod |
+------+------+-----+
| 0001 | jhon | 123 |
+------+------+-----+
| 0002 | paul | 567 |
+------+------+-----+
```

i want to change to

```
+------+------+----------+
|  cc  | name | tax_code |
+------+------+----------+
| 0001 | jhon |   123    |
+------+------+----------+
| 0002 | paul |   567    |
+------+------+----------+
```

(the column name "*cod*" changes to "*tax_code*" and contents does not change)

looking in http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL.html
appears some sql code, but nothing to work with column names.

**there is some procedure in sql in orientdb to change column names?, or at least some "sp_RENAME" equivalent command?**

Answer (score 3):

ALTER PROPERTY is the correct way to do this, but there are some gotchas.  First when you rename a property it doesn't not actually remove the old property, it will just copy the values into the new one.  If you had the following class / data like you say

```
CREATE CLASS USER;
CREATE PROPERTY USER.cc Integer;
CREATE PROPERTY USER.name String;
CREATE PROPERTY USER.cod Integer;

INSERT INTO USER SET cc=0001, name="john", cod=123;
INSERT INTO USER SET cc=0002, name="paul", cod=567;
```

The data will look like this:

```
+------+------+-----+
|  cc  | name | cod |
+------+------+-----+
| 0001 | jhon | 123 |
+------+------+-----+
| 0002 | paul | 567 |
+------+------+-----+
```

Then you alter the property:

```
ALTER PROPERTY USER.cod NAME tax_code;
```

Now we have:

```
+------+------+-----+----------+
|  cc  | name | cod | tax_code |
+------+------+-----+----------+
| 0001 | jhon | 123 |    123   | 
+------+------+-----+----------+
| 0002 | paul | 567 |    567   |
+------+------+-----+----------+
```

At this point the USER class doesn't have the cod proeprty any more, but some of the record do.  We can then remove the old values from the classes:

```
UPDATE USER REMOVE cod;
```

And finally we get to what you want.

```
+------+------+----------+
|  cc  | name | tax_code |
+------+------+----------+
| 0001 | jhon |    123   | 
+------+------+----------+
| 0002 | paul |    567   |
+------+------+----------+
```

Hope this helps.  If you are still having issues, can you post some SQL that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alter property <class-name>.cod name tax_code
```

Hope it helps

Regards.

Comment: i do: 
`alter property user.cod name tax_code`

and orientdb says: 

`com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Property 'user.cod' not exists` 

**:(**

Comment: this exception appears because the property user.cod doesn't exist anymore and it has been replaced with tax_code.